# Is it possible to install VM (any) on a GPU?

Tags: virtual-machine, gpu, adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to install VM (any) on a GPU?  If so, then what about two GPUs (with dual GPU support)?

My purpose is to run heavy Photoshop tasks on two GPUs to get a fast result.

Comment: You seem to be confused on both fronts. You *always* run VMs on your CPU. You *always* use PCI passthrough if you need to access a GPU from one.

Comment: so i can run photoshop on any gpu ? also is there a guide for "PCI passthrough" and what about running a photoshop on two gpu , thanks .

Comment: Only certain Hypervisors support PCI-E passthrough and requires your hardware to support it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically no, VM's use the cpu, and about "photoshop on two GPUs" issue, it's basically "no" too:

> ### Does Photoshop take advantage of more than one graphics processor or graphics card?
>
> Photoshop currently doesn't take advantage of more than one graphics processor. Using two graphics cards does not enhance Photoshop's performance.
>
> Multiple graphics cards with conflicting drivers can cause problems with graphics processor accelerated features in Photoshop.
>
> For best results, connect two (or more) monitors into one graphics card.
>
> If you have to use more than one graphics card, make sure that they are the same make and model. Otherwise, crashes and other problems can occur in Photoshop.

[Photoshop graphics processor (GPU) card FAQ](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-cc-gpu-card-faq.html)

Comment: @y.h. No problem. If it's useful or seems best or correct, don't forget to upvote (green up arrow) &/or select as correct (check-mark).